# Methods with class names as their type

Tags: java, methods

Why should I make a method with a type as classname not primitive type like void, int...?

```
BufferedImage imagetest(String file) throws IOException{
    return null;
}
```

Why is the type BufferedImage not void or anything like that? I know it's a stupid question but I hope that someone could help.

Comment: It's not that it's a stupid question. It's that there isn't any question. See [ask]. Read more carefully https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/.

Comment: You can use void if there is not a return and primitive types may also be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `BufferedImage` is the datatype returned. It could any other class type such as `String`, or primitive type, such as `int`.

```
// This method returns a String
String method() {
    return "";
}

// This method returns an int
int method() {
    return 0;
}
```

You would use `void` if you don't need to return a value, and just want to **do** something.

```
// This method doesn't return anything
void method() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: More accurately, instance-based void methods are often mutators for the instance they're defined in.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison They sometimes are, but that is still **doing** something rather than **returning** something.

Comment: Most often they are.  Actually I'm having trouble coming up with an example for a void instance method which *isn't* mutating the instance, hence I said "more accurately."

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Well you may have a compiler with a **Node** class which represents some parse tree node, with an **analyse** method that is void and just ensures semantic validity on the node. (As I did in my compiler)

Comment: Not sure what your design would be in that instance.  Validation is best done in the ctor when possible as an object in an invalid state is not desirable. I'm glad you've thought of an example, however I stand by my statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a return type, and it allows the method to return something to the caller. In this case a `BufferedImage` (which is always `null`). But you could return a valid `BufferedImage` thus de-coupling the logic of providing a buffered image from the caller.